# CSS3 Transitions Speed at Runtime

Tags: javascript, css

I am using CSS3 Transitions, and I am wondering if once the animation is started with:

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
```

Can I somehow increase the speed which was pre-set using:

```
-webkit-transition: all 10s linear;
```

I want the speed to be **2s** using jQuery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears you can with `this.style["-webkit-transition"]`

http://jsfiddle.net/X5shh/

#### HTML

```
<div class="one"></div>
```

#### CSS

```
.one
{
    -webkit-transition: all 10s linear;
    width:200px;
    height:20px;
    background:green;
}
.two
{
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
}
```

#### jQuery

```
$("div").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("two");
    this.style["-webkit-transition"] = "all 2s linear"
});
```

### EDIT

or

```
this.style["-webkit-transition-duration"] = "2s";
```

Comment: @UmairAshraf hm... I've hack together a way to do it... but I don't know why it works and would really like someone to explain it :( http://jsfiddle.net/s2mLm/1

Comment: great. me neither understands it

Comment: may be when you remove the other transition is applied and when you add again, the whole css applied again except the transition property.

Comment: @UmairAshraf I was just going over it in chat with some other javascript developers and it seems it's probably because setTimeout gives a minimum of a 4ms delay.  It also appears that the webkit minimum is 10ms.  Therefore, this gives it enough time to make the changes...... *in theory*